# Optimizing multiple utility functions

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, game-theory

I'm currently working with the [Bertrand Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6806.pdf) mathematical model. The model basically allows multiple sellers to compete in different market shares at the same time.

The utility function for each seller is:

$$u_i(x)=x(\alpha_i + \sum_{j \in N(i)}\beta_{i,j} \overline{F}_j(x))$$

Where $N(i)$ is the set of neighbors of $i$ (his competitors), $\beta_{i,j}$ is the size of the market share of the seller $i$ and $j$ and $\overline{F}_j(x)$ is the inverse $C.D.F$ function that says the chance of the firm $j$ to choose the price of $x$ or **higher**. Last but not least, $\alpha_i$ is the size of the captive market of $i$.

The article states the following:

> A sketch solution (of an equilibrium) specifies a sketch and, additionally, it defines values $F_r(t)$ for every seller $r$ and point $t$ in the set $T$ of boundary points of the sketch. These values must satisfy the following linear program (LP1) in the variables $\{u_i\}_{i\in[n]}$, $\{F_r(t)\}_{r \in [n],t \in T}$ (observe that the values of $t \in T$ are not variables).

The model is long to be explained and I'll try to provide an example. Consider the following competition among three firms:

Firm $f_2$ compete against the firm $f_1$ and $f_3$ at the same time for the market share $\beta_{1,2}$ and $\beta_{2,3}$ respectively. Firm $f_1$ and $f_3$ are not competitors.

From the utility formula, we have:

$$u_1(x)=x(\alpha_1 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_2(x))$$
$$u_2(x)=x(\alpha_2 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_1(x) + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_3(x))$$
$$u_3(x)=x(\alpha_3 + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_2(x))$$

It is known (from the article) that there is an equilibrium for this competition, with $\alpha_1 > \alpha_2 > \alpha_3 > 0$ and $1 = t_1 > t_2 > t_3 > 0$ and $t_k \in [0,1]$:

$$u_1(t_1)=u_1(x) \forall x \in [t_2,t_1]$$
$$u_2(t_1)=u_2(x) \forall x \in [t_3,t_1]$$
$$u_3(t_1)=u_3(x) \forall x \in [t_3,t_2]$$

Now, the linear program that must be satisfied in this equilibrium:

$$u_1=t_1(\alpha_1 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_2(t_1))$$
$$u_1=t_2(\alpha_1 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_2(t_2))$$
$$u_2=t_1(\alpha_2 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_1(t_1) + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_3(t_1))$$
$$u_2=t_2(\alpha_2 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_1(t_2) + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_3(t_2))$$
$$u_2=t_3(\alpha_2 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_1(t_3) + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_3(t_3))$$
$$u_3=t_2(\alpha_3 + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_2(t_2))$$
$$u_3=t_3(\alpha_3 + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_2(t_3))$$

$$u_1 \geqslant t_3(\alpha_1 + \beta_{1,2} \overline{F}_2(t_3))$$
$$u_3 \geqslant t_1(\alpha_3 + \beta_{2,3} \overline{F}_2(t_1))$$

$$\overline{F}_1(t_3) = 1$$
$$\overline{F}_2(t_3) = 1$$
$$\overline{F}_3(t_3) = 1$$
$$\overline{F}_2(t_1) = 0$$
$$\overline{F}_3(t_1) = 0$$
$$\overline{F}_1(t_1) > 0$$

$$\overline{F}_3(t_1) < \overline{F}_3(t_2)$$
$$\overline{F}_1(t_2) < \overline{F}_1(t_3)$$
$$\overline{F}_2(t_1) < \overline{F}_2(t_2)$$
$$\overline{F}_2(t_2) < \overline{F}_2(t_3)$$
$$\overline{F}_3(t_2) < \overline{F}_3(t_3)$$

What I'm looking for are values for $t_k$ and $\overline{F}_i(t_k) \in [0,1]$ that will satisfy the constraints above but I'm not sure what is the objective function in this case. I haven't worked with Linear Programs before.

**My question is**: since I must find the values for $t_k$ and $\overline{F}_i(t_k)$ that combined will give the best utility for every seller, is it correct to consider the objective function as follows?

$$maximize\ u = \frac{u_1(t_1) + u_1(t_2)}{2} + \frac{u_2(t_1) + u_2(t_2) + u_2(t_3)}{3} + \frac{u_3(t_2) + u_3(t_3)}{2}$$

I'm considering that, if competitors are trying to optimize their utilities, the sum of their best utilities would lead to a global utility that I have to maximize, but I'm not sure if I can do it, I believe I'm losing some basic concept of Linear Programming. Remember that $u_1(t_1) = u_1(t_2)$ and so on.

I'm a bit lost, I'd appreciate any hints, names or articles that I should read to see if I'm indeed following the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If t is not a variable wouldn´t that mean that $t_i$ and therefore $F_{\tau}(x)$ are constants? And you have to 
 maximize the objective function w.r.t $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_{i,j}$ ?

Comment: In the model, $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_{i,j}$ are constants (size of the market share) and, by working with some equalities I'm able to find every $t_k$ and $\overline{F}_r(t_i)$, but this demands manual calculation which I think that the LP would come with them. So I believe that those values must be optimized, I didn't understand why that quotation states that $t_k$ are not variables. I can improve the question with more details regarding how $t_k$ and $\overline{F}_r(t_i)$ are used if necessary.